# NavigationEvents is not working when use going back

Tags: react-native, expo, avaudioplayer

I am building a small sound player page. I am using expo-av library. 
I got noticed when the user going forward {NavigationEvents onWillBlur } is working and when he goes backward it's not executing.

What I need to reach are : 
1) Stop sound playing when the user leave page either backward or forward.
2) If user presses play twice the sound is being played twice so I don't want it to be played again if it's already running

If there is any other library could be use instead of expo-av ?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import {AntDesign, Entypo} from '@expo/vector-icons';




const PlaySound =  ({link}) => {

    const [error, setError] = useState('')

    const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();

    const mySound = async () => {

        try {
         await soundObject.loadAsync({ uri : link });
         await soundObject.playAsync();

       } catch (err) {
           setError('Wait while uploading your sound');
       }

    }

    const stopSound = async () => {
        try {
            await soundObject.stopAsync(mySound);
        } catch (error) {
           setError('You must Play Sound First')
        }

    }

    const pause = async () => {
        try {
            await soundObject.pauseAsync(mySound);
        } catch (error) {
            setError('Something went wrong !!! Please try again');
        }
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <NavigationEvents onWillBlur = {stopSound} />
            <Text>Play Sound</Text>
            <View style = {styles.row}>
            <TouchableOpacity
            onPress = {mySound}>
                <AntDesign name = 'caretright' size = {25} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
            onPress = {stopSound} >
                <Entypo name = 'controller-stop' size = {25}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
            onPress = {pause}>
                <AntDesign name = 'pause' size = {25} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            {error ? <Text>{error} </Text> : null }
        </View>
    );
};



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    row : {
        flexDirection : 'row',
        justifyContent : 'space-between',
        marginVertical : 10
    }
});


export default PlaySound;
```

Answer (score -2):

For the problem 1 in which you have to stop player when user leaves the page. You can use useEffect hook. It will be something like that,

```
useEffect(() => { 

   return () => {
     stopSound();
  }
}, []);
```

So in the above useEffect hook, the returned function will run when component will unmount from screen (forward or backward).

For the 2nd problem, you have to disable play button to avoid multiple clicks. You can create a state using `useState` hook and make it `false` on Play button click and pass this playButtonState to disable prop of Play Button Touchable Opacity.

I hope it's clear to you now.

Comment: The question is in regards to NavigationEvents.